Permission Denied on googleapis using Vertex AI for embedding
So I'm currently working on a feature that uses Vertex ai's text-embedding-004 and It was working before. I've downloaded the Google CLI... I've logged in and everything. But now its saying I don't have permission. I've tried logging in again but was to no use. I'm gonna be honest my Google credentials are just in my .env file but I haven't seen any documentation requiring them else where and I've ran the program the night before and now it's not working.
Been getting errors like these all night:
RuntimeError: Failed to embed texts: 403 Permission 'aiplatform.endpoints.predict' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/-----/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/text-embedding-004@default' (or it may not exist). [reason: "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED"
domain: "aiplatform.googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "resource"
  value: "projects/-------/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/text-embedding-004@default"
}
metadata {
  key: "permission"
  value: "aiplatform.endpoints.predict"
}
]

I don't know if I've skipped a step in setting up the google api or what.
I've tried generating a key from IAM and I also added that to my .env file but still i honestly don't know if I've mixed up the variables.

See liyangxia's answer:
Add the Vertex AI User role to your service account.
Note: It may take up to 5 minutes for your changes to propagate.
